# Maven compiler plugin, build helper plugin does not generate class files

Tags: maven, maven-2, m2eclipse, maven-compiler-plugin

I am trying to convert an existing project into a maven project. It has 3 modules and one of the modules has multiple source folders.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUlm7.png

A maven clean and install or an eclipse clean does not create the class files in the classes and test-classes folder. The project structure gets created by there are no class files there.

The following plugin configuration is defined in the parent pom.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/main/java/**/*.*</source>
                    <source>src/report/java/**/*.*</source>
                    <source>src/architect/java/**/*.*</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>add-test-source</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals><goal>add-test-source</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/test/java/**/*.*</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <debug>false</debug>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>src/main/java/**/*.*</include>
                    <include>src/report/java/**/*.*</include>
                    <include>src/architect/java/**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals><goal>testCompile</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <testIncludes>
                    <include>src/test/java/**/*.*</include>
                </testIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you adding different location than src/main/java or src/test/java? Is this really necessary?

Comment: Because in this legacy project there are multiple source folders and there is a bi-directional dependency between them. If I make a particular source, say for ex. in this case "report" src folder, to be a separate maven module then I don't know how to resolve this bi-directional dependency.

Comment: Based on the information you gave it looks you need to separate the multiple source folders into separate modules.

Comment: Ok if I do that, and say I create a separate module _GAS2Report and _GAS2WebApp depends on certain functionality present in _GAS2Report and vice-versa. Then should I be adding a dependency in each of them?

Comment: If you have such dependencies than yes. But if you have a circular reference than there is something wrong...

Answer (score 3):

For me the mvn plugin in eclipse doesn't generate the proper structure either.
Try running mvn eclipse:eclipse in cmd. That did it for me.

Also you used the phase 'generate-test-sources'. This doesn't seem to work try 'generate-sources'.

Comment: if anyone knows why the generate-test-sources doesn't work. Add it in comment.

Comment: The short answer is that you need to execute the 'generate-test-sources' goal before 'maven-eclipse-plugin' executes so run 'mvn generate-test-sources eclipse:eclipse'.

I had a go at answering in more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20463195/1410035

Answer (score 1):

According to [Using MOJO build-helper-maven-plugin to add more source folders to MAVEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561345/using-mojo-build-helper-maven-plugin-to-add-more-source-folders-to-maven) you should **not** define additional source directories **again** via the includes tag; define them just in *build-helper-maven-plugin* and that is it.

Also you can try to associate *add-source* goal with an earlier Maven phase, like *initialize*. Generally, the earlier the better.

```
<phase>initialize</phase>
<goals>
    <goal>add-source</goal>
</goals>
```

In my case, my mistake it was to bind it to *compile* phase. Despite my *build-helper-maven-plugin* was defined before *maven-compile-plugin* in the *pom.xml*, somehow *default-compile* task kicked in first and silently ignored my extra source directories causing some unexpected errors further down the build. Order of steps bonded to same phase should follow order of appearance in pom.xml but, well, not always.

Check that you see in your log:

```
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-source (add-gen-source) @ deepclone-sample-project-1 ---
[INFO] Source directory: E:\dev\workspace...\src\main\generated added.
```

Handy trick: Make a deliberate error in your code, just to check that compiler really go through you extra directories. If compilation does not fail instantly then the issues in not about not generating class files files but really about compiler configuration. You can exclude incremental build issues or similar more esoteric issues.

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) in [build helper maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/)'s `add-source` goal, you should specify a **directory** in `<source>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. So now all my resources are correctly getting copied into the classes and test-classes folder. But I still don't have any class files.