# Maven: Why does adding test source via build helper not work when generating eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

Our maven pom.xml specifies to add an additional source and test-source folder if a certain profile (here "java8") is activated. The corresponding part of the pom looks like the following

```
    <profile>
        <id>java8</id>
        ....
        <build>
            <plugins>
                ....
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-test-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                            <goals><goal>add-test-source</goal></goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/test/java8</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

According to http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html this appears to be the correct specification.

Running `mvm install -P java8` I see that the additional tests are performed as expected.

However, running `mvm eclipse:eclipse -P java8` the additional test source folder does not appear in eclipse `.classpath`.

**Question: How do I have to configure maven to add the test source folder to the eclipse configuration?** Is the above behavior a bug or a misconfiguration?

Answer (score 5):

*Having spent some time experimenting with this, I can give a partial answer to my own question (hopefully saving some time of other developers):*

If one uses

```
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals><goal>add-test-source</goal></goals>
```

instead of

```
                            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                            <goals><goal>add-test-source</goal></goals>
```

then the test source folder is added to the eclipse .classpath (and it is added as a test folder). I.e. I am executing "add-test-source" in a different phase now.

In other words the profile looks like this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>java8</id>
        ....
        <build>
            <plugins>
                ....
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-test-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals><goal>add-test-source</goal></goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/test/java8</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

This looks like a "workaround". It still contradicts the specification on http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 2):

rather than using eclipse:eclipse, you can use the http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/ plugin to open maven `pom.xml` projects.

Once you install that plugin in maven you will be able to take advantage of the [m2e maven plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html), which can map any maven phase into the eclipse build life cycle. 
in our example you will need to add something like this to your pom.xml:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
     <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
     <configuration>
       <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
         <pluginExecutions>
           <pluginExecution>
             <pluginExecutionFilter>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
               <goals>
                 <goal>add-test-source</goal>
               </goals>
               </pluginExecutionFilter>
               <action>
                 <execute>
                   <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                 </execute>
               </action>
            </pluginExecution>
         </pluginExecutions>
       </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

**Important**

this will only work if you install the m2e plugin and use it to open maven projects.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, the plugin is working as expected.

When you run `mvn install -P java8`, you are invoking the phase `install`. In effect, maven executes all the phase prior to `install`, including `generate-test-sources` phase and `test` phase... before it really executes `install`. Because your plugin's goal is bound to `generate-test-sources` phase, that's why in this case you see your tests added in the class-path and run.

When you run `mvn eclipse:eclipse -P java8`, however, you are invoking a plugin's goal (in particular, `eclipse` goal of `eclipse` plugin), not a build life-cycle (phase). According to the eclipse plugin's [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html), only the `generate-resources` phase will be invoked. Be noted that `generate-resources` doesn't not "include" `generate-test-sources` (see more [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)), so in this case, your build-helper plugin does not get called.

If I guess correctly, you're trying to run your test in Eclipse with the profile `java8` enabled. In that case, one way to do it (without having to work around) is right click on your project, click Maven, in the Active Maven Profile input box type in `java8` ->OK. Now right click in your project and choose Run As -> JUnit Test (or whatever test framework you're using). Make sure you use the latest Eclipse version (Kepler 4.3.1 as of now) as it has a built-in m2e plugin which has improved a lot from the original m2e.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue as you Christian Fries and I came to the same conclusion as you about binding the `add-test-source` goal to the `generate-sources` phase instead of the `generate-test-sources` phase.

The problem is that when we run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, we are actually directly calling a plugin so only that plugin will run. The reason the `generate-sources` phase is executed is explained in the plugin's doco (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html):

```
Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase generate-resources prior to executing itself.
```

What we want is to be able to tell the plugin to execute the `generate-test-sources` phase before itself and then run. Note that maven will run all the phases up to and including the one you specify (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) so we don't need to say run `generate-sources` AND `generate-test-sources` because simply specifying the latter is enough. Anyway, we can test this situation by running (the order matters):

```
mvn generate-test-sources eclipse:eclipse
```

...and for me, this did exactly as we expected. You can see from the output that the build-helper-maven-plugin is run to add the test sources and THEN the maven-eclipse-plugin runs and picks it up.

Now we have a new problem because AFAIK you can only bind a plugin to a phase (so it runs when the phase is run) and not the other way around.

The (sort of) solution is to bind the `build-helper-maven-plugin` and the `maven-eclipse-plugin` (in that order, so define the plugins in your POM in that order) to the `generate-test-sources` phase and then instead of running `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, run:

```
mvn generate-test-sources
```

So we have a POM that looks like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <directory>src/test/java8</directory>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>eclipse</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I know it's not perfect because people will still run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and cry when it doesn't work. Also, the `maven-eclipse-plugin` will run as part of anything that runs the `generate-test-sources` phase (i.e. `mvn clean install`) which isn't so bad if it doesn't steamroll custom settings people have but if it is a problem you could move this stuff into a profile, bind it to a different phase that doesn't run as part of a build (like `clean`) or create a new lifecycle phase.